# Beamer: Visualize overlay borders in handout mode

Tags: beamer, overlays, printing

I want to display the slide areas of a frame in handout mode.

A possible solution could look like this:

```
\begin{frame}  % presentation mode
    On slide 1 \\
    \pause
    On slide 2
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}  % handout mode
    \fbox{On slide 1}$_{1-2}$    \\
    On slide 2
\end{frame}
```

My motivation is to know from my printed handout where I drew the overlay.

Does anybody know an option or package offering this or something similar?

Comment: So you want to have the handout mode give “presentation hints” so that the presenter knows what's presented on which slide of each frame?  I think creating an overlay/mode specification-aware macro and using the `handout` mode specifications can do that for you.  Maybe not with the subscripts, though.

Comment: Yes, @Matthew, I'm looking for "presentation hints" in handout mode -- subscripts are not important, they were just my first idea of such hints.
Is creating such a macro complicated?

Comment: I can think of a couple of ways to give the hints that are easier than this one (for instance, putting every frame of the slide into the handout), but I don't have time to flesh it out ATM.  Maybe I'll try later.

Comment: As it stands, I really don't think this is clear: feel free to tell me otherwise!